# Regular expression optional match start/end of line

Tags: regex

How do I optionally match the start `^` or end `$` of a line in a regular expression?

For example:

`/(?<=[\s\^])/` does not match starts with space character or start of line.

My problem was in PHP matching the following.

```
$str = '**bold** **bold** **bold**';
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)\*\*(.+?)\*\*(?=\s|$)/', '<strong>\\1</strong>', $str);
```

My edge cases that were the bold at the start and end of the string were not being matched. Some edge cases I came across with other variants were matching within strings, matching chains of asterisks, and countless other problems.

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s|\>)[\*]{2,}(?=[^\s\*])(.+?)(?<=[^\s\*])[\*]{2,}(?=\s|\<|$)/', '<strong>\\1</strong>', $str);
```

Comment: If you remove them, then they're optional.

Comment: You are looking for these functions http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you insist on matching after a **whitespace character** or **the start of the line**, use an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (not the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)). Assuming your regex flavor supports alternations in [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
/(?<=\s|^)\w+/m
```

But probably you are looking for a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), `\b`. They match on the start or end of a word (exactly on the change from a word character to a non word character or the other way round).

Comment: I think you need [] for the charset before `|`, ie `/([?<=\s]|^)\w+/m`

Comment: @ssppjj, that is not a charset, it is a lookbehind assertion. Completely different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the anchors. Without the anchors, the regex will be matched anywhere in the string you are searching.

Comment: Added an example with look-behind to show what I am attempting to match, space character or start of line.