# Struggling at creating correct regex

Tags: python, regex

1. I try to get a match for every 'word' (lowercase or capital):
   **(word|WORD)**
2. No chars or numbers before or following:
   **(?<![^a-zA-Z0-9])**(word|WORD)**(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])**
3. In case 'word' is at the start or end of the string:
   **^|**(?<![^a-zA-Z0-9])(word|WORD)(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])**|$**

It simply doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `(?i)\bword\b`? Not sure if python supports that. (.. or can only all caps or all lowercase is supported?)

Comment: Python supports the case insensitive flag, but in case OP wants fixed case only `\b(word|WORD)\b` with `re.findall` should do the trick.

Comment: `word` is just an accronym right? There really is no such thing as a _word_ boundary in regex since there is no language specified in  regex constructs. What you're looking for is your own definition of a boundary as you define it. Lets say you have a letter `W` you don't want letters or numbers surrounding it `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])W(?![a-zA-Z0-9])` Presto your own boundary definition. Lets say you want a `Q` surrounding it, or end/begin of string. `(?<![^Q])W(?![^Q])` and again a new boundary definition. The idea of a word in regex is meaningless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
import re

text = "123 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, word WORD WoRd consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 123"

pattern = re.compile(r'\bword\b', re.IGNORECASE)

for word in pattern.finditer(text):
    print(word.group(0))
```

Which would yield

```
word
WORD
WoRd
```

---

`\b` is the short form for

```
(?:(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

Which reads

```
(?=\w)(?<!\w) # positive lookahead making sure there's a word character coming
              # negative lookbehind making sure theres' n word characte preceding
|             # or
(?<=\w)(?!\w) # the other way round
```

So, yes

```
(?:(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))word(?:(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

would yield the same matches as above but seems a bit unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

(?<![^a-zA-Z0-9]) is a double negative. You're saying it should NOT match if the character before the main expression is NOT in [a-zA-Z0-9], that is, it can only match if the that character is in [a-zA-Z0-9]. Just remove the ^: (?<![a-ZA-Z0-9]).

You're use of the string boundaries ^ and $ are confusing here, but you shouldn't need them if you're using negative look-behind and negative look-ahead.

So, switch to **(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])(word|WORD)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])**.

That said, @user3783243's comment about \b is a better option. \b is a 'word boundary', which represents exactly what you are trying to capture. Python does support it: [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Related: [Regular expression optional match start/end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15734322/2860127)

So you should actually just use **\b(word|WORD)\b**.